# List not being overwritten in expected manner

Tags: python, list

I am new to Python. What my code is *supposed* to do is check the line against an existing list, if the  line is not already in the location file it asks for the user to assign a value to it and updates the list it is validating against. I have verified that the lists are reading from the text files correctly (in the below format).

The result it is giving me is a never-ending loop because it is not finding the line in the list even after it has been added. I would expect it to break after the user enters 'n' and then some string value.

(Also there will be an additional line for `if dummyvar in location:`, but I haven't gotten to that yet.)

**Variables**

```
 from_location = [ company, address, city, state ] #changes line by line
 location = [[ 'company a', 'address a', 'city a', 'state a', 'classification a'],
             [ 'company b', 'address b', 'city b', 'state b', 'classification b']]
 loc_opt = ['classification a', 'classification b', 'classification c']
```

**Code snippet:**

```
        while from_location not in location[:][0:-1]:
                ftext=("This location has not been indexed. Please enter the " +
                      "location name or input one of these prompts \n" + 
                      " 'l' to list all acceptable locations\n" + 
                      " 'n' to add a new location\n" +
                      " 'p' to print the full line of information\n" +
                      "Company:   " +  str(from_location[0]) + " \n" +
                      "Address:   " + str(from_location[1]) + "\n" +
                      "City:   " + str(from_location[2]) + "\n" +
                      "State:   " + str(from_location[3]) + "\n")

                dummyvar = input(ftext)
                if dummyvar == "l":
                    print("Current Location Options are:  \n ")
                    for item in loc_opt:
                        print("  ", item ,"  ")
                if dummyvar == "p":
                    print("Entire Line :  ", spline,"\n")
                if dummyvar == "n":
                    new_location=input("Please input new location:\n")
                    new_location.upper()
                    new_location = [new_location]
                    loc_opt = loc_opt + new_location
                    location = location + [from_location + new_location]
                    print(location)
```

**Full Code**

```
print("Press Ctrl C with the Python window selected \n"
      "at any time to stop the program. A loud beep "
      "will sound \n when the program is finished.\n\n")
date = 00000000
counter = 1
dummyvar="q"

ref_fp =(r"filepath")
loc_opt_fn = open(ref_fp + "LOCATION OPTIONS.txt")
loc_ref_fn = open(ref_fp + "LOCATION REFERENCE.txt")

loc_opt = loc_opt_fn.read().split("\n")


location = loc_ref_fn.read().split("\n")

for index in range(len(location)):
    location[index]=location[index].split("\t")

while len(str(date))!= 8 or (date < 20180101 or date > 20301231):
    date = input("What date is the file would you like to clean"
             "( yyyymmdd year like: 20190227). \n\n")
    date = str(date).strip()
    try:
        date = int(date)
    except:
        print("\nNo letters please!\n")
        date = 000

fp1 = (r"anotherfilepath")
fp2 = ( r" filename.txt")

fpr= (r"yetanotherfilepath")
filepath = fp1 + str(date) + fp2

with open(filepath) as source:
    for line in source:
        line.strip("\n")
        spline = line.split("\t")
        if counter == 1:
            spline.append("FROM")
            spline.append("TO")
        else:
            spline.append("")
            spline.append("")
        if spline[0] == "NC":
            #So we've added two columns, FROM and To
            #And we are only operating on the lines that are NC
            #Because that excludes the exceptions.
            #Now we want to check and see if the From and
            #To information is in the reference lists.
            from_location=[spline[5],spline[7],spline[9],spline[10]]
            to_location=[spline[13],spline[15],spline[17],spline[18]]

            while from_location not in location[:][0:-1]:
                    ftext=("This location has not been indexed. Please enter the " +
                          "location name or input one of these prompts \n" + 
                          " 'l' to list all acceptable locations\n" + 
                          " 'n' to add a new location\n" +
                          " 'p' to print the full line of information\n" +
                          "Company:   " +  str(from_location[0]) + " \n" +
                          "Address:   " + str(from_location[1]) + "\n" +
                          "City:   " + str(from_location[2]) + "\n" +
                          "State:   " + str(from_location[3]) + "\n")

                    dummyvar = input(ftext)
                    if dummyvar == "l":
                        print("Current Location Options are:  \n ")
                        for item in loc_opt:
                            print("  ", item ,"  ")
                    if dummyvar == "p":
                        print("Entire Line :  ", spline,"\n")
                    if dummyvar == "n":
                        new_location=input("Please input new location:\n")
                        new_location.upper()
                        new_location = [new_location]
                        loc_opt = loc_opt + new_location
                        location = location + [from_location + new_location]
                        print(location)

    counter += 1 
import winsound
winsound.Beep(600,500)
print("\n\n\n----------------------------Processing is finished.----------------------------\n\n\n")
```

Comment: What are you expecting `while from_location not in location[:][0:-1]:` to do? `location[:][0:-1]` is the same as just `location[0:-1]`, which is all the elements of `location` except for the last element.

Comment: @Barmar location is a list of lists. aka `[ [a,b,c] , [d,e,f] ]` I thought that `location[:][0:-1]` would return `[ [a,b] , [d,e] ]`.....

Comment: It seems like you're expecting that to make a vertical slice of the 2-dimensional list, but that's not how it works.

Comment: @Barmar .... Yep... That sounds like what I'm wanting to do.... I wasn't familiar with the term 'vertical slice'. I'll start looking into that concept.

Comment: What you want is `[l[0:-1] for l in location]`

Comment: It's not a concept, I just made up the term.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you very much. I will give that a try. (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`location[:][0:-1]`doesn't remove the last element from each element of `location`. It's equivalent to `temp = location[:]` followed by `temp[0:-1]`. `temp` is just a copy of `location`, and then it returns a list with all but the last element of that.

You can do what you want with a list comprehension:

```
while from_location not in [l[0:-1] for l in location]:
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you very much for your help!